# Implement Envoy OAuth2 filter with disabled routes

Tags: oauth-2.0, routes, envoyproxy, disable

I deployed an envoy as a side car to manage oauth2. Everything work fine for all the resources and the client is redirected to the OIDC in order to authenticate.
Here is a part of my conf (managed in a Helm chart):

```
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          access_log:
          - name: envoy.access_loggers.file
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
              path: /dev/stdout
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: my-service
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  cluster: my-service
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.oauth2
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.oauth2.v3.OAuth2
              config:
                token_endpoint:
                  cluster: {{ .Values.back.envoy.oidc.name }}
                  uri: https://{{ .Values.back.envoy.oidc.address }}/oidc/token
                  timeout: 5s
                authorization_endpoint: https://{{ .Values.back.envoy.oidc.address }}/oidc/authorize
                redirect_uri: "%REQ(x-forwarded-proto)%://%REQ(:authority)%/oidc/callback"
                redirect_path_matcher:
                  path:
                    exact: /oidc/callback
                signout_path:
                  path:
                    exact: /oidc/signout
                credentials:
                  client_id: {{ required "back.envoy.oidc.client_id is required" .Values.back.envoy.oidc.client_id }}
                  token_secret:
                    name: token
                    sds_config:
                      resource_api_version: V3
                      path: "/etc/envoy/token-secret.yaml"
                  hmac_secret:
                    name: hmac
                    sds_config:
                      resource_api_version: V3
                      path: "/etc/envoy/hmac-secret.yaml"
                forward_bearer_token: true
                # (Optional): defaults to 'user' scope if not provided
                auth_scopes:
                - user
                - openid
                - email
                - homelan_devices_read
                - homelan_topology_read
                - homelan_devices_write
                # (Optional): set resource parameter for Authorization request
                #resources:
                #- oauth2-resource
                #- http://example.com
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
            typed_config: {}
```

Now I'd like that some of the exposed resources don't need to be authenticated.
I see in the doc the Oauth filter doc "Leave this empty to disable OAuth2 for a specific route, using per filter config." (see https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/extensions/filters/http/oauth2/v3/oauth.proto#envoy-v3-api-msg-extensions-filters-http-oauth2-v3-oauth2config)
This phrase make me think that it may be possible.
I tried to manage it changing my conf throught virtual_hosts this way :

```
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: no-oauth
              domains: ["*"]
              typed_per_filter_config:
                envoy.filters.http.oauth2:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.oauth2.v3.OAuth2
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/api/v1/myResource1"
                route:
                  cluster: my-service
            - name: my-service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/api/v1/myResource2"
                route:
                  cluster: my-service
```

I have the error : [critical][main] [source/server/server.cc:117] error initializing configuration '/etc/envoy/envoy.yaml': The filter envoy.filters.http.oauth2 doesn't support virtual host-specific configurations

Any idea ? Did someone implement Envoy OAuth2 filter with disabled routes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at my envoy logs, I realized that path is know as header ":path".
The `pass_through_matcher` math the header.

Then only adding:

```
pass_through_matcher:
  - name: ":path"
    prefix_match: "/healthz"
  - name: ":path"
    prefix_match: "/api/v1/myResource1"
```

in my conf without the lua filter (see my previous answer) it works.

Answer (score 0):

For information, I found a workaround:

I added a LUA filter before my OAuth2 one:

```
          - name: envoy.filters.http.lua
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua
              inline_code: |
                function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
                  request_handle:headers():add("X-Path", request_handle:headers():get(":path"))
                end
```

In order to add the path in a header.
Then I can use this element of conf Oauth2:

- pass_through_matcher
  (repeated config.route.v3.HeaderMatcher) Any request that matches any of the provided matchers will be passed through without OAuth validation.

So I add this to my OAuth2 filter:

```
                pass_through_matcher:
                  - name: "X-path"
                    prefix_match: "/healthz"
                  - name: "X-path"
                    prefix_match: "/api/v1/myResource1"
```

Then my /api/v1/myResource1 requests (and healthz also) don't need authentication (are disable from the OAuth2)  while my /api/v1/myResource2 requests need it.

I still have got the unanswered question:
What do the OAuth filter doc means with :"Leave this empty to disable OAuth2 for a specific route, using per filter config."